# REST API sending webhooks to front end

Tags: spring, spring-boot, webhooks

If my rest API has a webhook setup where it is getting information, how do I notify the front end that new information is received and is ready to be sent? Can the API only send data to front end if the front end requests it? Using Spring boot and Vuejs.

Comment: Maybe you are talking about Real-time simplementation between front-end and back-end by using socket.io or you should read more about lifecycle methods hooks for vuejs or angular or any front-end framework to understand where you should put your REST API call

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never used Vue.js or Spring boot, but I'm familiar with React and since both are front-end libraries I believe they work similarly. I believe what you're looking for is Socket.io which will create a real-time, bidirectional and event-based communication between the client's browser and the server. So when you receive an event in your webhook you communicate whatever you want to the client.

Here is an example on how to build it using vue.js and Node.js, I'm sure you can tailor it to your needs.
https://medium.com/js-dojo/build-a-real-time-chat-app-with-vuejs-socket-io-and-nodejs-714c8eefa54e